# Not able to pull graphdb-workbench from docker hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub, graphdb

I am trying to pull and run the `graphdb-workbench` image from docker hub using the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 -e GRAPHDB_URL=127.0.0.1:7200 graphdb-workbench
```

I get the following error :

> Unable to find image 'graphdb-workbench:latest' locally docker: Error
> response from daemon: pull access denied for graphdb-workbench,
> repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
> requested access to the resource is denied.

How can i fix this ?

Thank you !

Comment: It seems like there is no _graphdb-workbench_ in the [Docker Hub registry](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=graphdb-workbench&type=image). I guess you should contact Ontotext support.

Answer (score 1):

As an additional info, the GraphDB workbench is bundled with GraphDB and is running on port 7200 as mentioned above.

The official GraphDB images are here: https://hub.docker.com/r/ontotext/graphdb/

And you can find additional information how to build your own here: https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-docker

However, there is no official image of the free version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following image : [dhlabbasel/graphdb-free](https://hub.docker.com/r/dhlabbasel/graphdb-free)

```
docker run --rm -it -p 7200:7200 dhlabbasel/graphdb-free
```

Afte you start the container, you can access the workbench on `http://localhost:7200`

#### Explanation

There are both official and user published images on docker hub.

- Official images are maintained by docker and can be pulled using only the image name and version. For example `ubuntu:latest`.
- User published images can be pulled using the user's username, image name and version. For example `logx7/sqlplus:latest`

You can search for images on https://hub.docker.com/. You'll not find an official image by the name `graphdb-workbench`. Searching for **graphdb** returns many results (For user published images, go with the most popular one if you can). Accessing the image page (repository), You'll find information about usage and configuration.